# ¿Cómo evitar que un Datalists de Bootstrap se mueva al hacer scroll?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, web

```html
<body>
<div class="container pt-5">
<label for="exampleDataList" class="form-label">Datalist example</label>
<input class="form-control" list="datalistOptions" id="exampleDataList" placeholder="Type to search...">
<datalist id="datalistOptions">
  <option value="San Francisco">
  <option value="New York">
  <option value="Seattle">
  <option value="Los Angeles">
  <option value="Chicago">
</datalist>

</div>


<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Estoy usando un datalists de Bootstrap, pero cuando aparece el menú desplegable y si hago scroll, el menú desplegable se mueve junto con el scroll. Estoy enfrentando un problema en Chrome, si se probó lo mismo en Firefox, el menú desplegable desaparece cuando se desplaza la página, adjunte el fragmento a continuación:

```
<label for="exampleDataList" class="form-label">Datalist example</label>
<input class="form-control" list="datalistOptions" id="exampleDataList" placeholder="Type to search...">
<datalist id="datalistOptions">
  <option value="San Francisco">
  <option value="New York">
  <option value="Seattle">
  <option value="Los Angeles">
  <option value="Chicago">
</datalist>
```

Comment: Buen día, ¿tienes algún CSS implementado?, también adjunta imágenes del problema que te surge para entenderlo mejor.

Comment: Puedes agregar un [repro] a través de un snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`) en la pregunta misma. Si llegas a insertar el snippet, no olvides agregar las bibliotecas relacionadas.

Comment: Buenos días, Si estoy usando css, he probado con dejar el elemento fijo pero nada. He dejado un ejecutable si haces clic en el input y haceis scroll el elemento del listado baja.